# Adding css to dynamically inserted elements

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, grid, append

I am trying to create a grid that maintains aspect ratio. I am doing this using div elements that append to the end of the previous until it has populated the whole screen. I try to use Jquery to apply CSS to the dynamically inserted elements but it only apply's to the first. I have my code [here](http://codepen.io/coltonf93/pen/qIixv).

### HTML

```
<div id='layer_grid'>
<div id='grid'>
</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#grid{
background-color:#c1c1c1;
border:1px solid black;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
}
```

### Jquery

```
for (var i=0;i<g_num;i++){
$('#grid:last').append('<div id="grid"></div>');
}
$('#grid').css({'width':gw,'height':gh});
```

This is not the first time this has happened to me. I don't get it. I thought Jquery was top down programming. Could someone explain why that doesn't work as well as suggest a method that does?

Comment: you cant use `id` for more than one element. thats why jQuery defaults it to the first element. u have to use classes instead.

Comment: Are we to assume that `gw` and `gh` are calculated somewhere that you are not showing?

Comment: Well, you can use more than one of a given ID if you choose, incorrect as it may seem to some. But there are draw backs to it. Such as invalid markup penalties with some search engines. JavaScript likes to assume that in using an ID there is only a single one to be found, and will apply it usually to the first one found on the page. Where as class will apply to all (but again with some playing around you can use class or id the same way, though not anywhere near considered proper usage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID selectors map to getElementById which will only return the first match for an ID since IDs are supposed to be unique.  `$('#grid')` will always select your first div with id="grid"

You should be using a class instead or creating a unique ID for each "grid", since IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Wow that was a rookie mistake. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks guys!